# Как настроить компиляцию и сборку многофайлового проекта на С++ в VS Code с помощью расширения Code Runner?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, отладка, компиляция, cmake

Например, у меня есть три файла:

```
//main.cpp 

#include "hello.h"

int main()  
{  
    print();  
    return 0;  
}
```

```
//hello.h   
#ifndef HELLO_H  
#define HELLO_H  

#include <iostream>  

void print();  

#endif
```

```
//hello.cpp  
#include "hello.h"  

void print()  
{  
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;  
    return ;  
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы они компилировались, запускались и отправлялись на отладку с помощью комбинаций клавиш. Смог найти только, как запустить один файл, но не несколько. Установлено расширение C/C++ от Microsoft. Буду благодарен за ответ

Comment: Конкретно про code runner не знаю. Я бы это решил настройкой системы сборки (make или cmake или ...). Научитесь запускать ее из консоли, потом прицепите эту команду к хоткею, например так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59849230/2752075

Comment: Я так понимаю, в Cmake файл нужно будет вносить изменения каждый раз, когда я создаю новый проект?

Comment: Его нужно будет копировать в каждый новый проект, или писать заново.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , видимо это самый оптимальный способ. Спасибо, буду разбираться.